Use of bitmask to remove undesired pixels from an image collection
I am using the HSL30 product to download monthly images for a single year. As it is now, I am not accounting for clouds, cloud shadows, snow/ice in the image collection. I would like to remove pixels contaminated with clouds, cloud shadows, snow/ice and moderate or high aerosol level. I have tried to use the bitwiseAnd() function without success (I have tried a lot of different things). Could you please help me remove the pixels mentioned above?
A table of the Fmask and the desired bits:



Bits
Meaning




Bit 1: Cloud
0: No


Bit 3: Cloud shadow
0: No


Bit 4: Snow/ice
0: No


Bits 6-7: Aerosol level
1: Low aerosol



Below is the code and the shp I am using:
var origbands = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/HLS/HLSL30/v002")
    .filterBounds(table);

// Define the list of bands you want to select
var selectedBands = ['B10'];

// Select the desired bands from the original image collection
var collection = origbands.select(selectedBands);

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
print("months", months);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2018, 2018);
print("years", years);

// Map filtering and reducing across year-month combinations and convert to ImageCollection
var yrMo = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
            var img = collection
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
              .mean()
              .set('year',y)
              .set('month',m);
            var bands = img.bandNames();
            return bands.map(function(n) {
              var image = img.select([n]);
              var image = image.set('system:index',ee.String(y).cat(ee.String(m)).cat(ee.String(n)));
              return image;
            });
        });
    }).flatten());
print("yrMo",yrMo);

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(yrMo,
                'test',
                {scale: 130,
                 crs: 'EPSG:3309',
                 region: table
                })


I think I managed to solve it. I followed a response from a previous question of mine where I wanted to export nighttime lights. The code is:
Map.centerObject(table);

var mask_vnpa2_img = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('Fmask');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 1).neq(0); // Extract bit 1 for cloud
  var cloudShadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).neq(0); // Extract bit 3 for cloud shadow
  var snowDetected = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).neq(0); // Extract bit 4 for snow

  var mask = ee.Image(1)
    .updateMask(cloud.not()) // High
    .updateMask(cloudShadow.not()) // Confident Clear
    .updateMask(snowDetected.not()); // No Snow

  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

var origbands = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/HLS/HLSL30/v002")
    .filterBounds(table)
    .map(mask_vnpa2_img);

// Define the list of bands you want to select
var selectedBands = ['B10'];

// Select the desired bands from the original image collection
var collection = origbands.select(selectedBands);

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
print("months", months);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2018, 2018);
print("years", years);

// Map filtering and reducing across year-month combinations and convert to ImageCollection
var yrMo = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
            var img = collection
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
              .mean()
              .set('year',y)
              .set('month',m);
            var bands = img.bandNames();
            return bands.map(function(n) {
              var image = img.select([n]);
              var image = image.set('system:index',ee.String(y).cat(ee.String(m)).cat(ee.String(n)));
              return image;
            });
        });
    }).flatten());
print("yrMo",yrMo);

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(yrMo,
                'test', 
                {scale: 130, 
                 crs: 'EPSG:3309',
                 region: table
                })

